# importing gmail contacts using php

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

May be am creating a lot of confusion with the previous post, so am trying redesign my entire post with my requirement and effort.

I want to fetch GMAIL contact list using PHP, to achieve this I have done the following thing:

1. Create Google Client ID with oAuth 2.0 protocol
2. Create 2 PHP files (oAuth.php and index.php)

Here is the code for 2 files:

oAuth.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
        <title>Email address list - Import Gmail or Google contacts</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        a:link {color:Chocolate;text-decoration: none;}
        a:hover {color:CornflowerBlue;}
        .logo{width:100%;height:110px;border:2px solid black;background-color:#666666;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="logo" >
        </div>
<br/>
        <div><b>Visit Tutorial: </b><a style="font-size:17px;" href="" >Import Gmail or Google contacts using Google Contacts Data API 3.0 and OAuth 2.0 in PHP</a></div>
            <br/>
        <div style="padding-left: 50px;">
<?php
$client_id = '1041526369396-kmnbhsos616eqcqimjrs07icn2c176ln.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$client_secret = '*************';
$redirect_uri = 'https://www.test.multicon.in/test9/oauth.php';
$max_results = 25;

$auth_code = $_GET["code"];

function curl_file_get_contents($url)
{
 $curl = curl_init();
 $userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url);   //The URL to fetch. This can also be set when initializing a session with curl_init().
 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);    //TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);   //The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect.    

 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent); //The contents of the "User-Agent: " header to be used in a HTTP request.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);  //To follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE); //To automatically set the Referer: field in requests where it follows a Location: redirect.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);   //The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); //To stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

 $contents = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);
 return $contents;
}

$fields=array(
    'code'=>  urlencode($auth_code),
    'client_id'=>  urlencode($client_id),
    'client_secret'=>  urlencode($client_secret),
    'redirect_uri'=>  urlencode($redirect_uri),
    'grant_type'=>  urlencode('authorization_code')
);
$post = '';
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $post .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
$post = rtrim($post,'&');

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,5);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$response =  json_decode($result);
$accesstoken = $response->access_token;

$url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results='.$max_results.'&oauth_token='.$accesstoken;
$xmlresponse =  curl_file_get_contents($url);
if((strlen(stristr($xmlresponse,'Authorization required'))>0) && (strlen(stristr($xmlresponse,'Error '))>0))
{
    echo "<h2>OOPS !! Something went wrong. Please try reloading the page.</h2>";
    exit();
}
echo "<h3>Email Addresses:</h3>";
$xml =  new SimpleXMLElement($xmlresponse);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
$result = $xml->xpath('//gd:email');

foreach ($result as $title) {
  echo $title->attributes()->address . "<br>";
}
?>
</div>
</body></html>
```

And index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
        <title>Import Gmail or Google contacts using Google Contacts Data API 3.0 and OAuth 2.0</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        a:link {color:Chocolate;text-decoration: none;}
        a:hover {color:CornflowerBlue;}
        .logo{width:100%;height:110px;border:2px solid black;background-color:#666666;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="logo" >

        </div>
<br/>
        <div><b>Visit Tutorial: </b><a style="font-size:17px;" href="http://test.multicon.in/test9/" >Import Gmail or Google contacts using Google Contacts Data API 3.0 and OAuth 2.0 in PHP</a></div>
            <br/><br/>
        <div align="center" >
            <a  style="font-size:25px;font-weight:bold;" href="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=1041526369396-kmnbhsos616eqcqimjrs07icn2c176ln.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https://www.test.multicon.in/test9/oauth.php&scope=https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/&response_type=code">Click here to Import Gmail Contacts</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now while clicking on the links in index.php it shows me that the My Project wants to access my Gmail contact...but when it takes me to the redirected page...it shows page not available whereas that page is there. I don't know whether am clear to you or not...if possible please check the link http://test.multicon.in/test9/index.php may be this will help you to understand my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally...I have resolved this issue, the my domain was not added with WWW records, that's why I was getting the error "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN", the moment I have added the WWW records for test.multicon.in,the error resolved